# How to disable email verification while user Sign up on Azure AdB2C?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have web application and created User Signin_signup user flow for user sign up process, but while user signup email verification code is asking for next process.

I want to disable the Email verification while user Signup on Azure AD B2C Tenant.

Comment: Have looked at Microsoft Documentation, first place to search for anything Azure related issues, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/disable-email-verification?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/disable-email-verification?pivots=b2c-user-flow#disable-email-verification).

Basically:

- Select User flows.
- Select the user flow for which you want to disable email verification.
- Select Page layouts.
- Select Local account sign-up page.
- Under User attributes, select Email Address.
- In the Requires Verification drop-down, select No.
- Select Save. Email verification is now disabled for this user flow.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to disable the email verification***

*In order to disable the email verification while user signup process, follow the below steps.

**Azure Portal > Azure AD B2C > User Flows > B2C_1_SigninSignup > Page layouts > Local account sign up page.**

[image]
once update the changes, try to create a user account, like below.

**Azure Portal > Azure AD B2C > User Flows > B2C_1_SigninSignup > Run User Flow**

[image]

**Email verification is disabled while user signup process.**

[image]